# Minimum version of notepad.exe to support unix newlines

Tags: windows, notepad, newlines

A while back, [Microsoft announced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/extended-eol-in-notepad/) their development build of notepad
finally supports unix style newlines (`\n`). However according to a
colleague, this is not the case in a Windows 10 testing environment in
which he tried this out: lines in a text file are all concatenated.

It is possible the testing image is outdated. What would be the minimum
version of the editor that contains this bugfix?

Also, was the fix backported to older versions of Windows?

Comment: What is the current value of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\fPasteOriginalEOL` and `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Notepad\fWindowsOnlyEOL`?  Instead of submitting a comment you should edit your question to include this vital and required information necessary to answer your question.  **The feature described in the blog article, describes a feature, that was introduced into 1809 which was released more than 2 years ago.**

Comment: In order to answer this question, you will have to indicated what build your "testing environment" has installed, otherwise your question cannot be answered.

Comment: @Ramhound: I don’t have access to that box. In any case, the question is about the version in which the bugfix was rolled out. The current version is of no import here.

Comment: If you are unable to enable the feature then the system is not running `Windows 10 version 1809`.  *Please edit your question to include the information about those keys.*  If they don't exist, that will confirm, that the system is not actually running a supported version of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Updated versions of Notepad are likely to only be included in feature upgrades and not backported. There isn't really a reason to push out new versions of Notepad via Windows update unless they are fixing security risks.

That said, I've converted a file using Notepad++ to use Unix LF-only line endings and it works and looks fine in normal Notepad on Windows 1809 (OS Build 17763.1217).

The notepad executable lists its product version as 10.0.17763.475, which matches the OS release version.

I suspect as long as you have a reasonably new feature update version of Windows then it should work.

The article you linked is from May 2018 and states

> Starting with the current Windows 10 Insider build

So it is likely that the first feature update after May 2018 would include the fix. That would be Windows 1809. Any version after that would have the fix. Any version before is unlikely to have this fixed.

That would agree with Ramhounds comment

Comment: The feature described in the article was introduced in `Windows 10 version 1809`, so any version of Notepad included with any version of Windows greater or equal to 1809, supports this feature.  If you are unable to enable the feature it means you are not running a unsupported version of Windows.  This feature cannot be enabled on `Windows 10 version 1803` or earlier.